# hibernate delete parent record if only no child record exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, exception

I want to delete a row from parent table if only there is no record in child table(parent to child one to many mapping). So when I try to delete parent record it give this exception.

```
   11:54:16,590 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) SQL Error: 2292, SQLState: 23000
11:54:16,590 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) ORA-02292: integrity constraint (DEPOT_OS.SYS_C007642) violated - child
 record found

11:54:16,596 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statem
ents
11:54:16,598 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-5) Exception occurred during processing request: could not execute statement; SQL
[n/a]; constraint [DEPOT_OS.SYS_C007642]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement: org.springframework.d
ao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [DEPOT_OS.SYS_C007642]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintV
iolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:161) [spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RE
LEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:681) [spring-orm-4.0.2.RELE
ASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:563) [spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RELE
ASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar
:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RE
LEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.ja
r:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95) [spring-tx-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207) [spring-aop-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy187.delete(Unknown Source)
        at com.ast.action.admin.AtAuthProfileAction.singledelete(AtAuthProfileAction.java:343) [classes:]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3
.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:249) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at com.ast.interceptors.admin.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:45) [classes:]
        at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246) [xwork-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99) [struts2-core-2.3.16.jar:2.3.16]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Fi
nal-redhat-14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_45]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:74) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:189) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:58) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3355) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:102) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:393) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:385) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:308) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.
Final]
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1159) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:404) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Fina
l]
        at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555) [spring-orm-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
        ... 79 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02292: integrity constraint (DEPOT_OS.SYS_C007642) violated - child record found

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:85)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:953)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3468)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedPreparedStatement.java:493)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:186) [hibernate-core-4.2.8.Final.jar:4.2.8.Final]
```

So then I try to catch that exception and pass my own error message to front end.

```
public int delete (int aapId) {
try{
    System.out.println("b4 catchedd.");
Session session = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
session.delete(session.get(AtAuthProfile.class, aapId));
}
catch (javax.persistence.PersistenceException  e) {
    System.out.println("Inside catch.");
    Throwable t = e.getCause();
    while ((t != null) && !(t instanceof ConstraintViolationException)) {
        t = t.getCause();
    }
    if (t instanceof ConstraintViolationException) {
        System.out.println("catchedd.");
    }
}
return 1;
```

}

But the exception never caught. Whats wrong with that code or any other wat to meet my requirment. I used spring JTA to transaction management.

Comment: Firstly Spring and JTA are two different thing, If you are using spring transaction support you have to show us like you are managing these transactions. Then can you update your question with more information about your problem?

Comment: CHeck if childs of parent exist exist then keep it as it is else delete record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your catch is never executed as `delete` is just a "marker" call. Hibernate will not issue the queries until a flush is called. In the normal case this happens on the end of a transaction and not when you call the delete or persist methods.

Assuming your public `delete` method is annotated with `@Transactional` this method is wrapped and on exit of that method the wrapper will call `commit`. This is where Hibernate flushes all changes to the datasource and commits the changes. So the exception happens outside of your method.

You will have to move your catch one level up. Outside the `@Transicational` method. Like this you should be able to catch the constraint violation.

Comment: I moved try catch before calling the service layer(@tranactional) method In action class(Struts2). Its works fine. Thanks.
Someone also sugested that can use AOP to handle exceptions in some article. Hope to try it also in free time. For now I go with this.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate won't do it. You'll have to implement it yourself:

```
   A a = b.getA();
   a.removeB(b);
   session.delete(b);
   if (a.getB().isEmpty()) {
      session.delete(a);
   }
```